# How to Wicket Redirect with large parameters?

Tags: java, wicket

I'd like to use a link in my Wicket (v1.4) page to redirect the user to an external site. Prefereably displaying the external page in a ModalWindow or similar.  My problem is that the external page I want to redirect to has a very long parameter as input (>75000 characters).  Typically, I would access the page via a POST, is something similar possible from Wicket?  My current (broken) implementation is as follows.

```
RedirectPage page;

....

final ModalWindow dialog= new ModalWindow("dialog");
            dialog.setPageCreator(new ModalWindow.PageCreator() {
                @Override
                public Page createPage() {
                    return page;
                }
            });
            add(dialog);

add(new IndicateModalAjaxSubmitLink("link") {

                @Override
                protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                    target.addComponent(form);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                        String url = <REALLY_LONG_URL_HERE>;
                        page = new RedirectPage(url);
                        dialog.show(target); 
                }
            });
```

Edit: It seems like the current character limit on the url is 4096.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any other choice, I think you can try to do what you want through Javascript, asynchronously loading the webpage with this huge page parameter (via `AjaxRequestTarget.appendJavaScript`) and displaying the result in your modal window.

Comment: I suspect this might work however it's not the solution I have implemented.  Instead I have re worked the call to the external site such that it is loaded via another servlet.  This new servlet  loads in the large parameter from the original wicket app and passes it onto the external site once it is called.  (In short, it's really messy).  Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.